# Dynamic SQL UNPIVOT and Select INTO temporary table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql

I know that there are a few questions out there on Dynamic SQL and Insert into temporary tables, but I cannot find an exact match for my particular problem. 
 I have data in 52 columns in ##tmp and I need to total these and store in ##tmp2.
 Note: The syntax works fine if I remove the first line

```
 select * into ##tmp2 from
```

It's the "Select Into" that I have a problem with! My current Dynamic query provides the following syntax, but I cannot get this to work. Currently the open bracket after the initial "from" has no matching closing bracket. 
I've tried various positions for the final ")" but get a mixture of

```
Incorrect syntax near ')' -- if placed at the end of the statement
Invalid column name 'wk' -- if added as  "from ##tmp) onto the second from"
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'. -- if added after ")) as U"
```

Here's the current syntax

```
select * into ##tmp2 from(
select x,y,sum(wk) as mysum  from ##tmp
  unpivot (wk for nwk in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],   [14],[15],[16],
[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],
[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50],[51],[52]))
 as u  group by x,y
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `select x,y,sum(wk) as mysum into ##tmp2  from ##tmp
  unpivot (wk for nwk in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],   [14],[15],[16],
[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],
[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50],[51],[52]) as u group by x,y`

Comment: Thanks @lad2025. Brilliant! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
select x,y,sum(wk) as mysum 
into ##tmp2 
from ##tmp 
unpivot (wk for nwk in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13], [14],[15],[16], [17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],‌​[33],[34], [35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50],‌​[51],[52])) as u 
group by x,y
```

Comment: Well it DID work! I swear it did. However, having put the statement into a Dynamic Query I now get a syntax error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.` (on the `unpivot` line) when using the above syntax. Am I going mad?? My syntax is exactly as above!

Comment: @MiguelH Probably missing bracket see updated `[52])) as u`

Comment: Brilliant! The missing bracket solved it! I should have spotted that myself!

Comment: @MiguelH This kind of typos are the worst, epsecially when you stare at wall of text for many hours. I know that pain :)